# An error occurred while creating the backup in magento

Tags: php, magento

I’m using Magento 1.9.0.1, and the backup feature doesn't work. When I click on <kbd>Magento System Backup</kbd>,  it says

> An error occurred while creating the backup.

And when looking at the results, we can see the same, `0` bytes and `empty` folders.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does system have write permissions to that directory?

Comment: Grammar correction and question formatting

Comment: Can you check and post the errorlog and system log in the question?